# Dropdown item select change event

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist1 containing items 2wheeler, 3wheeler.
If I select 2 wheeler dropdownlist2 should be open with items gear and non gear.
if I select gear I want to open textbox to write bike model name.
else if I select non gear I want to open just label.

Comment: "Hope you getting my question." - it is totally unclear

Comment: you need to be clear and specific. Show some `html` code

Answer (score 0):

Your design page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowDDL2" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowControls" Visible="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

Your code behind:

```
protected void ShowDDL2(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ddl2.Visible = true;
}

protected void ShowControls(object sender, EventArgs e){
    TextBox1.Visible = TextBox2.Visible = Label1.Visible = Label2.Visible = true;
}
```

Is this what you need? But I don't see a logic in this...

Comment: @Rajat then what do you need?